# How to get Recent Activity stories via FQL and Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-stream-story

I just want to get message from facebook, like 'Yanyang and Sina Sadegh are now friends', I see Piyush Mangalick said "some recent Activity stories now exposed via FQL and Graph API and these stories, along with tags of people mentioned in the stories are now available through the FQL stream table and the Graph API Post object" in the link 'http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/'

But while I check stream table, I found the column 'story' or 'story_tags' is not exist in steam table till now. It always throw 'stroy is not a member of the stream table', why?

And while I use Graph API to get feed 'me/feed', it just show the comments and likes and shares, no friends relation ship like I want or music info.

How could I get the recent activity stories via FQL and Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Without wanting to ask a silly question, did you enable the migration in your app's advanced settings?

I just tried an FQL query of the form `fql?q=select description, tagged_ids, message_tags from stream where source_id = me()` and it's including 'was tagged in a photo' and other similar stories, as expected

Comment: I also see your question -- "enable the migration in your app's advanced settings". But I just use rest api before, not a APP, how could I enable it?

Comment: Go in to your app's settings page, choose the advanced settings tab, and enable that migration

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but I corrected it using by using the `description` field instead of `story`.

It seems that `description` is the appropriate field in FQL and `story` is the corresponding field in the Graph API.